# Lattice unit cells

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, matter

Just wondering if anyone had any links to good web based interactive models of lattice unit cells? Especially primitive unit cells? The one I used to use was built with flash so it no longer works :(
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/The143DBravaisLattices/)'s one from WolframAlpha.

Comment: @Sebastiano OP did ask for a link and there's not much more to it, really. I think the best thing for this question would be lots of answers with different links. What more could I have done?

Comment: Hi, retract my comment. Excuse me. I am ofen in TeX.SE and I see many answer with the only link. My best regards and +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano It's ok, don't worry!

Answer (score 1):

It is not very difficult to make them with [3DMol](http://3dmol.csb.pitt.edu/) in html5 (for almost any browser).

I made this page: http://homepage.lnu.se/staff/pkumsi/1FY805/Gold_cluster_rotate.html

The source code is easily legible and quite short. And as you can see there, I am not even good at web-page layout...